# I can't read sqlite data in coffescript

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite, express, coffeescript

Hello i try to read somethink from my sqlite in coffe.script when i wrote it JS it works well but now i got some problem

Coffee.script:
I am new in coffeescript and i am wondering what am i doing wrong... Any tips guys ? :)

```
app.get('/indeks',
  (req, res)->
    tab = []
    i = 0
    db = new sqlite3.Database("xxx.sqlite3")
    tab = []
    i=0
    console.log("Jestem przed dbHandler")

    db.each("SELECT yyy FROM zzz", @dbHandler, @dbFinal

    dbHandler:(err, row)->
      console.log("I am in handler dbHandler")
      if err
        console.log("Error: " + err)
      else
        tab.push(row)
        console.log(row)  

    dbFinal:()->
      console.log("I am in dbFinal")
      console.log("Final: " + tab)
      console.log("Response")
      res.send(tab)
      db.close()
   )
)
```

Now code in JS:

```
app.get('/indeks', function (req, res, next) {

    var db = new sqlite3.Database("xxx");
    var tab = new Array();
    var i=0;


    function dbHandler(err, row){
        if (err) {
            console.log("Error: " + err);
        } else {
            tab.push(row);
            console.log(row);
        }
    }    

    function dbFinal(){
        console.log("Final: " + tab);
        console.log("Response");
        res.send(tab);
    }

    db.each("SELECT zzz FROM yyy", dbHandler, dbFinal);
    db.close();

});
```

Comment: What's the error you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look into the transpiled coffee code? When using something like `dbHandler:(err, row)->` a JSON-Object with the property dbHandler is generated. This is why you cannot pass dbHandler and dbFinal to the `db.each` call. This only works when defining a class.

Additionally, you got an unmatched bracket in the line 10 and a bracket too much in the last two lines.

You should always check the compiled code (respectively check whether it even compiles). [Here](http://js2coffee.thomaskalka.de/) is a helpful site for this. There, you can even convert your JS code to coffeescript.